# Read a ASCII file based on its headlines Matlab

Tags: matlab, bigdata

I have a file like this:

```
ID  LHW  dms  
1   105.28 1 
2   357.01 0 
3   150.23 3
```

My question is if it is possible to get one column value based on the headline? I can of course get `LHW` by its column position, 2, but I would like to get it by just reading `LHW`.

The reason for this is that I have two large data sets (about `50 000 rows x 80 columns`) with the same variables, but in different positions. If I could get the right column value based on its headline, it would save a lot of programming time.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about existing of some built-in function for your purposes. But we can create it manually. For example:

```
function [result] = readByName( A, filename )
if ~ischar(A) % check input parameter (you can delete this sectionif you want)
    display('Error: First argument must be a char array!');
    massiv = -1;
    return
end

fileID = fopen(filename);                       % open file
title = textscan(fileID, '%s',3);               % read title
number = cellfun( @(x) strcmp(x,A), title{1});  % find wanted column  

if ~any(number)   % one more check
    display('Error: wrong name of the first argument');
    massiv = -1;
    return
end

data = textscan(fileID, '%f %f %f');     % read data
result = data{ number==1 };              % get wanted column
end
```

Example of its implementation:

```
readByName('ID', 'yourdata.txt')
```

Answer:

```
ans =

 1
 2
 3
```

Now you can load data just by name. Now you have to modify it a bit if you will have columns with same name.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I however just get "Empty matrix: 0-by-1" as result. Can it be that I have misinterpreted the formate data file?

Comment: I think the problem is your real file is a bit different: my algorithm works (I checked it at your data example). You just need to adapt it to your data: 1. if you use a different number of columns correct `data = textscan(...)` string. 2. try to use debugger and find where exactly it goes wrong. 3. If there still be an error, put your code here, I will try to help you

Comment: I solved it by replacing the last line in your function (reslut = data...) with

[DataColumn] = find(number == 1)

Comment: Thanks again for the help! :)

Comment: @KGB91 Aha! No problem!
If my solution helped you can you mark it as a right answer? :)

Comment: Another option for your last couple lines (which may speed things up) is: `fStr = repmat({'%*f '}, 1, numel(number)); fStr(index) = {'%f '}; result = textscan(fileID, [fStr{:}]);`

Comment: @gnovice I got the idea, but can you please clarify some moments: Why you use `%*f`? And second one - is `number` must be instead of `index`?

Comment: Yeah, that was a typo. `index` should be `number`. And `%*f` will skip that field instead of returning it.